# @PostConstruct not invoked in PhaseListener

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, postconstruct, phaselistener

I am using jsf2.2 with wildfly 8.1 and javaee7.

My CDI bean injection in the phaselistener works as expected, but the @PostConstuct method is never invocked

I have tried to annotate the phaselistener with @javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScope, SessionScope and Dependent to no avail.

Apart from naming, this is the exact thing i do in my post construct.

```
//@ApplicationScope
//@SessionScope
//@Dependent
public class MyPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

   @Inject
   @Any
   private Instance<MyOrderedUrlHandler> myOrderedUrlhandlers;
   private Map<String, List<MyOrderedUrlHandler> orderedUrlHandlersMap;

   @PostConstruct
   void mapOrderedUrlHandlers() {
      LOG.info("Executing postconstruct");
      orderedUrlHandlersMap = Maps.newHashMap();

      for(final MyOrderedUrlHandler urlhandler : myOrderedUrlhandlers) {
         final String handles = urlhandler.url();
         final List<MyOrderedUrlHandler> registeredHandlers = orderedUrlHandlersMap.get(handles);

         if(registeredHandlers == null) {
            registeredHandlers = Lists.newArraList();
         }
         registeredHandlers.add(urlHandler);
         orderedUrlHandlersMap.put(handles, registeredHandlers);
      }
   }
}
```

Method level injection also works fine.

Is it the case that @PostConstruct callback is not part of jsf phaselistener specs?

Comment: Show your code. You might be breaking the contract for `@PostConstruct`

Comment: What if you and an explicit default constructor?

Comment: @Kukeltje What do you mean default constructor? The phaselistener is invoked, the problem is that the '@PostConstruct' is not being called. How would an explicit default constructor help in this case?

Comment: I see it is already answered.  It was just a guess, since I've noticed before (not sure anymore where and when)  that a missing constructor prevented another annotated method to work correctly.  Luckily this does not seem the case now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to section 5.4.1 of the [JSF 2.2 spec](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=344), `PhaseListener` is not a managed bean but is injectable.

According to section 5.4.2, managed beans must support lifecycle annotations `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy`.

Since a `PhaseListener` is not a managed bean in the sense of JSF, it does not follow from the spec that a phase listener implementation must support `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: Even though i accept this as the answer, it seems way weird that dependency injection is supported without life-cycle event support.